# Derivation of the Pitman estimator

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, conditional-expectation

I am having trouble with a step of a proof in the book Statistical Estimation Asymptotic Theory by  Ibragimov and Has'minskii.

Lemma 2.1: Let $T=T(X_1, ..., X_n)$ be an arbitrary statistic with $\mathbb{E}_\theta|T|<\infty$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}_\theta[T | X_2 - X_1, ..., X_n - X_1] = \int_{R^k}T(X_1 + \theta - u, ..., X_n+\theta-u)\frac{\Pi_1^nf(X_j-u)}{\int_{R^k}f(X_j - v)dv}du.
$$

Following is the snapshot from the book:
[image: the previous page]
[image]

The proof begins with: Denote by $I$ the right hand side of the equation above. $I$ is a function of $X_2-X_1$, ..., $X_n-X_1$ only. Therefore it is sufficient to prove that for any statistic $z$ of the form $z(X_2-X_1, ..., X_n-X_1)$ the equality $\mathbb{E}_\theta[zI] = \mathbb{E}[zT]$ is valid.

I cannot see the jump between the final equality, $\mathbb{E}_\theta[zI] = \mathbb{E}[zT]$, and the main statement of the lemma. How does one imply the other?

### Edit: Adding definition of $\bf W$

The other missing definition is that $\bf W$ satisfies

1. ${\bf W}(u;v) = w(u-v)$
2. $w(u)$ is defined and nonnegative, $w(0)=0$,and continuous at $u=0$ but is not identically $0$
3. $w(u) = w(-u)$
4. the sets $\{ u:w(u) < c \}$ are convex for all $c>0$

Comment: It is unclear to me why $I$ is a function of $X_2 - X_1, \ldots, X_n - X_1$ if $T$ is just "*an arbitrary statistic*".  And what is $f$ in $I$?

Comment: $f$ is the density of $X_i$. I believe the random variables $X_i$ are i.i.d. and therefore the joint density just becomes the product.

Additionally the only way I have been able to make sense of why $I$ is a function of $X_2-X_1...$ is to read the sentence as "[Then] $I$ is a function of...", which I don't love doing but I can't see any other way to interpret that?

Comment: That's exactly my point, it is not trivial at all to show that $I$ is a function of $X_2 - X_1, \ldots, X_n - X_1$.  So on top of the question you asked, this question should be answered in the first place.  While it is clearly not true for general i.i.d. densities, it might be true under more conditions (which should be associated with Pitman estimator) which may be shown elsewhere not included in the screenshot you clipped.

Comment: I've added the page prior to the initial one. This includes the more rigorous definitions of $X$ and $f$ but, to my knowledge, the passage in question is the first occurrence of $I$ (and the Pitman estimator) in the entire book. Note that it doesn't claim the $X$'s are independent. That is only actually stated 3 full pages prior in a separate example, however the derivation below equation (2.2) and in the proof of the lemme itself suggests independence was assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (2.4), $I\ $ is a function of $(X_2 - X_1, \ldots, X_n - X_1)$ by a mere change of variable in the integral, namely
\begin{align} I &=\int_{\mathbb R^k}T(X_1 + \theta - u, ..., X_n+\theta-u)\frac{\prod_1^nf(X_j-u)}{\int_{\mathbb R^k}\prod_1^nf(X_j - v)dv}du\\ &=\int_{\mathbb R^k}T(\theta - \nu, ..., X_n-X_1+\theta-\nu)\frac{\prod_1^nf(X_j-X_1-\nu)}{\int_{\mathbb R^k}\prod_1^nf(X_j -X_1 - v)dv}d\nu
\end{align}
The identity that constitutes the lemma then follows from
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta[z(X_2-X_1,\ldots)I(X_2-X_1,\ldots)] = \mathbb{E}_\theta[z(X_2-X_1,\ldots)T((X_1,X_2,\ldots)]$$
because (i) $I$ is a function of $(X_2-X_1,\ldots)$ only and (ii) itsatisfies the [orthogonal projection property associated with conditional expectations in measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra). For instance, here is the very first definition found in Steve Lalley's U of Chicago [coursenotes](http://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/383/ConditionalExpectation.pdf):

> **Definition 1.** Let $(Ω, \mathfrak F , P )$ be a probability space and let $\mathfrak S$ be a
> σ−algebra contained in $\mathfrak F$. For any real random variable $X ∈ L^2(Ω,\mathfrak F ,
> > P )$, define $\mathbb E (X | \mathfrak S )$ to be the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto the
> closed subspace $L^2(Ω,\mathfrak S , P )$.

The property$$\mathbb{E}_\theta\big[z(X_2-X_1,\ldots)\big\{I(X_2-X_1,\ldots) -T(X_1,X_2,\ldots)\big\}\big]=0$$expresses the $L^2$ *orthogonality* between measurable functions of $(X_2-X_1,\ldots)$ and $I-T$.

Comment: Can you clarify what the projection property associated with conditional expectations is or where I could find more information?

Comment: Thank you! The added little bit has given me enough direction to see it now. I field this field beautiful and yet entirely unintuitive. Still building that working knowledge of definitions and relationships.